Jest function refers to another file through correct import
I am facing a weird problem in test environment with Jest.
I am importing the getProdutsFactory from the correct path. (eslint used).
import {
  apps,
  clearFirestoreData,
  initializeAdminApp,
} from "@firebase/rules-unit-testing";

import { batchWriteProductsFactory } from "../../src/repository/firestore/products/batch-write-products.js";
import { getProductsFactory } from "../../src/repository/firestore/products/get-products.js";
import { generateProductsArray } from "../common/faker.js";

describe("Firestore get product", () => {
  let db: FirebaseFirestore.Firestore;
  const userId = "1";
  beforeEach(async () => {
    db = initializeAdminApp({ projectId: "test-project" }).firestore();
    const mockProducts = await generateProductsArray(10);
    await batchWriteProductsFactory(db)(mockProducts, userId);
  });

  afterEach(async () => {
    await clearFirestoreData({ projectId: "test-project" });
    await Promise.all(apps().map((app) => app.delete()));
  });

  it("should do something", async() => {

    await getProductsFactory(db)({
      userId: "1",
      field: "id",
      direction: "desc",
      limit: 10,
    })(undefined);
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });```

Somehow when i run the test, it refers to another file.
This is the error
 FAIL  __test__/unit-tests/firestore-get-products.unit.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: (0 , get_products_js_1.getProductsFactory) is not a function

      52 |   product: {
      53 |     batchWriteProducts: batchWriteProductsFactory(firestoreClient),
    > 54 |     getAllProducts: getProductsFactory(firestoreClient),
         |                                       ^
      55 |     insertProduct: insertProductFactory(firestoreClient),
      56 |   },
      57 |   productCategory: {

      at Object.<anonymous> (../src/repository/firestore/index.ts:54:39)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../src/repository/firestore/products/get-products.ts:3:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (unit-tests/firestore-get-products.unit.test.ts:8:1)

i also have the Factory Function inside a repository
import { Firestore } from "@google-cloud/firestore";

import { clearCollectionFactory } from "./collection/clear-collection.js";
import { viewCollectionFactory } from "./collection/view-collection.js";
import {
  ProductsCategoriesFirestoreSchema,
  ProductsCategoryFirestoreSchema,
} from "./models/category.type.js";
import {
  ProductFireStoreSchema,
  ProductsFireStoreSchema,
} from "./models/product.type.js";
import { UserFireStoreSchema } from "./models/user.type.js";
import { batchWriteProductsFactory } from "./products/batch-write-products.js";
import { insertProductFactory } from "./products/insert-product.js";
import { batchWriteProductsCategoriesFactory } from "./products-categories/batch-write-categories.js";
import { getProductsCategoriesFactory } from "./products-categories/get-categories.js";
import { getUserFactory } from "./users/get-user.js";
import { insertUserFactory } from "./users/insert-user.js";
import { updateUserFactory } from "./users/update-user.js";
import { getProductsFactory } from "./products/get-products.js";

const firestoreClient: FirebaseFirestore.Firestore = new Firestore({ projectId: process.env["PROJECT_ID"] as string });

export const firestoreRepository = {
  user: {
    getUserByUsername: getUserFactory(firestoreClient)("username"),
    getUserByEmail: getUserFactory(firestoreClient)("email"),
    getUserById: getUserFactory(firestoreClient)("user_id"),
    insertUser: insertUserFactory(firestoreClient),
    updateUserLastLogin: updateUserFactory(firestoreClient)("last_login"),
    updateUserProductsSynced: updateUserFactory(firestoreClient)("are_products_synced"),
    updateUserProductsCategoriesSynced: updateUserFactory(firestoreClient)("are_products_categories_synced"),
  },
  product: {
    batchWriteProducts: batchWriteProductsFactory(firestoreClient),
    getProducts: getProductsFactory(firestoreClient),
    insertProduct: insertProductFactory(firestoreClient),
  },
  productCategory: {
    batchWriteProductsCategories: batchWriteProductsCategoriesFactory(firestoreClient),
    getProductsCategories: getProductsCategoriesFactory(firestoreClient),
  },
  collection: {
    viewCollection: viewCollectionFactory(firestoreClient),
    clearCollection: clearCollectionFactory(firestoreClient),
  },
};

if i delete the function within the Repository, the test will pass. I am pretty sure the file was imported correctly in the test.
